# EventEmitter from a directive is not handled in Parent

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I created a directive that shows or hides a component depending on the user claims.

**is-allowed.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { SecurityService } from 'app/_security/security.service';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appIsAllowed]'
})
export class IsAllowedDirective {

  @Output() isReady = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
    private ss: SecurityService,
  ) { }

  @Input('appIsAllowed') set isAllowed(claimType: any) {
    if (this.ss.hasClaim(claimType)) {
      this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
      this.notAllowed(false);
    } else {
      this.notAllowed(false);
      this.viewContainer.clear();
    }
  }

  notAllowed(isAllowed: boolean) {
    debugger;
    this.isReady.emit(isAllowed);
  }
}
```

Then I have 2 components. 1 is the admin-template component and the other is sample component.

**admin-template.component.html**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="sampleToUpdate">
  <app-sample *appIsAllowed="'Admin'" (isReady)="notifyIfAllowed($event)"  [sampleData]="sampleToUpdate"></app-sample>
</ng-container>
```

**admin-template.component.ts**

```
notifyIfAllowed($event: boolean) {
    debugger;
    if (!$event) {
      this.toastr.error('You are not allowed to do this operation', 'Unauthorized', {
        closeButton: true,
        progressBar: true,
        timeOut: 3000
      });
    }
  }
```

**sample.component.ts**

```
 @Input() sampleData: SampleData;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.sampleData);
  }
```

Everything seems to be working as expected in the directive but somehow, the parent component's `notifyIfAllowed()` is not getting invoked since it doesn't go to its breakpoint. What I am trying to achieve is; when `<app-sample>` cannot be shown because of the `claims` that is handled in the `directive` I need a toastr to notify the user.

Comment: Can you try remove * before directive name and try?

Comment: I did that already Sir

Comment: Can you create sample issue reproducible stackblitz?

Comment: @SivakumarTadisetti, thank you for your help Sir. I just changed the way it renders.